# Does vector allocates memory consecutively for std::moved objects

Tags: c++

If I reserve vector with certain size, then I have a loop where I take local variable and then `emplace_back(std::move(local_object))`, since `std::move` transfer the ownership of the memory. Will the vector have the elements with consecutive locations?

Comment: I think you are confusing memory that an object (might) allocate with memory an object occupies. The former is transferred to the vector, the latter is not.

Comment: "Moving" in C++ doesn't actually move the _object,_ it just asks the target object to _take ownership_ of any allocations owned by the source object.

Comment: *"since `std::move` transfer the ownership of the memory"* -- Over-use of "the" can be as misleading as over-use of "it". Which memory is "the" memory? A more precise formulation: *since `std::move` transfers the ownership of the memory **that the local object owned** (not that the local object occupies)*. (Also, this transfer is dependent upon the local object following conventions, as `std::move` by itself transfers nothing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not rules of language, but  architectural concepts:

- You have to remember that storage occupied by object is not owned by said object. It is owned by something hierarchically higher. That can be another object or process, or a function in case of automatic storage.
- Taking ownership of allocated dynamic memory supposes to take control of pointer returned by a new expression. Once gained it controlled until by holder of that value and to stop existing it should be "deleted". Otherwise it will be "lost", leading to so-called memory leak. But it's preferred to consider term "ownership of resource" to abolish details of implementation and designate that prticular entity has access to said resource and controls its "life".

To analyze expression `emplace_back(std::move(local_object))`  one should consider that

1. Vector doesn't own resources of stored objects. It takes owner of resource used to store objects.
2. If a stored object of type T owns some resources, they are NOT passing ownership to container. They continue own them.
3. `emplace_back` constructs a *new* object of type T in memory location owned by `vector` if there is available space. Otherwise it would reallocate `vector`'s storage to gain required resource. Arguments of `emplace_back` are used as arguments of constructor for type T.
4. `std::move` doesn't move anything. It is a standardized mnemonic for a *xvalue expression*, equivalent to static cast for result of expression used as its argument to a *rvalue reference* type.
5. As argument of `emplace_back` is an rvalue reference to original object of type T,  so called "move constructor" is invoked. If constructor was defined for the type T by user, then it is user's responsibility for what action were done *after* vector finished allocation.
6. If no user-defined move and copy constructors and assignment operators were defined for T as well there is no user-defined destructor, then move constructor is implicitly declared by compiler. Implicitly declared move constructor follows defined semantic for all members, in order of declaration:

   - For all class-type sub-objects move-constructors are called, starting with base class sub-object if applicable.
   - For all fundamental types and arrays content of their storage is copied.
7. Implicitly declared move constructor is defined as deleted if T contains any non-static member of T that is not movable, direct or virtual base class that is not movable, or if T is a union-like class and has a member with user-defined move constructor.
8. Ability to be moved implies presence of access to unambiguous and not deleted move constructor in present context.

Therefore `emplace_back` would result in transfer of ownership from original object of type T to *newly constructed* object, only if user had defined move constructor for object of type T or any of its sub-objects and whole conglomerate is movable. If that requirement is not met, then construction of new object by call of copy-constructor will be considered. Otherwise it is nothing but a shallow copy.

Answer (score 3):

It moves the contents of the memory of `local_object`, it does not magically move the memory itself. The `vector` has its own storage which is always continuous.

Comment: it must be changing the pointers right? What does it mean "move" here?

Comment: @debonair Moving is an instruction for a new/existing target object to take ownership of any allocations made by the source object. Put another way, it tells the target object "make yourself equal to this other object, but you don't have to keep this other object the way it is, so if you can steal its state to make this more efficient, please do so." The most straightforward move implementation is `swap(*this, other)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` is always using consecutive (contiguous) memory locations. But if `std::move` is actually helping, odds are it's because your objects don't store their own memory entirely locally (with some of the data being stored in dynamically allocated memory), and that non-local memory will remain non-local (the pointers to it are moved over as part of the move construction, but where they point remains unchanged).

In short, the parts that don't benefit from `move` will be contiguous, and the parts that do benefit from `move` will remain where they were.

Answer (score 2):

A vector always stores elements in consecutive locations.

When you add new elements, the `vector` may need to allocate new memory and relocate the data in order to make the elements fit in consecutive locations.

The `reserve` step makes one memory allocation and you are guaranteed to be able to add the number of elements you've reserved space for without relocations.

[`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) doesn't move anything. It's used on `local_object` to indicate that it may be *moved from* which makes the move constructor eligable. It's the move constructor that does the actual transfer of ownership.

If you have raw pointers in your object you must write the copy and move constructors yourself (as well as the copy and move assignment operators). See [the rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).